# How can I call a service API running in an another port via rest template?

Tags: java, rest, nginx, resttemplate, grpc

There are two services -  /getEmployeeSalaryDetails  and /CalculateAverageSalary

> **nginx** redirect to 10092,if a user hit the API- /getEmployeeSalaryDetails.

*I want to call a /getEmployeeSalaryDetails from  /CalculateAverageSalary internally (from port 8080).*

I tried to call /getEmployeeSalaryDetails API via restTemplate, I want to know the flow ***,Does this restTemplate call go via ngnix ,Since it's http call.***

and add on to the doubt,

> Should I need to write a grpc (.proto) to call a service 
>   /getEmployeeSalaryDetails which is inside an rpm ,running in a server.
>   or restTemplate is enough ?

Note:

> /getEmployeeSalaryDetails API is written in GO lang inside an rpm,
>   /CalculateAverageSalary is written in java inside a war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q-1:- I tried to call /getEmployeeSalaryDetails API via restTemplate, I want to know the flow ,Does this restTemplate call go via ngnix ,Since it's http call.

It depends on URL(protocol://host:port) in your resttemplate. Say, your getEmployeeSalaryDetails and CalculateAverageSalary service are on same host, and you use http://localhost:8080/getEmployeeSalaryDetails URL in rest-template from CalculateAverageSalary, then it will not go to nginx as localhost:8080 resolves locally.

But, if you use [http://somehost.com/getEmployeeSalaryDetails](http://someurl.com/getEmployeeSalaryDetails) from CalculateAverageSalary, then it will not go to nginx, then call goes to 8080 via proxy if so.